# Using and formating an RSS feed

Tags: html, css, feed, atom-feed

Ok, here is my RSS feed link http://jacobnlsn.com/wordpress/?feed=rss. And I am looking to format it so it fits in the upper right hand spot of my header.  My website is here [http://jacobnlsn.com/](http://jacobnlsn.com). Its the black box in the upper right hand corner. How would I go about doing something like that?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an RSS parser, which also caches the feed to save everyone time and money:

http://lastrss.oslab.net/

And a ticker or scroller - a decent one can be found here:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/rsspausescroller/

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own RSS parser in the language of your choice. As you use PHP, [SimpleXML functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) provide a simple solution.